# Avoiding errors when adding rows to blank table using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, arcgis-10.4

I am having problems when using ArcPy with ArcGIS Desktop to add in a set number of rows into a .dbf table.

What should I do to prevent these errors?

Here is a sample code that gives me errors:

```
##########setup###########
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env


##########parameters##########

ws =  r'C:\Users\ddsouth\Documents\Python_tests'
env.workspace = ws

newFile = "adding_table_rows_test_1"
newFileFull = os.path.join(ws, newFile) + ".dbf"

###########code###############

#create the table
arcpy.CreateTable_management(ws, newFile)
arcpy.AddField_management(newFileFull, "RouteName", "TEXT", "", "", 15)
arcpy.AddField_management(newFileFull, "DepotName", "TEXT", "", "", 15)

#edit the table
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(newFile, ["ROUTENAME"])

for q in range (0,10):
    cursor.insertRow((str(1),))
del cursor

print "Completed."
```

The creation of the table goes fine the first time, then when it comes to the edit portion I get the following error message:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 26, in <module>
SystemError: error return without exception set
```

Then if I run the program again, I get a different error, this time during the creation of the table, even if I have the "Overwrite the outputs of geoprocessing operations" option selected:

```
Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 18, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 15715, in CreateTable     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 001143: Background server threw an exception.
```

I also noticed that while the tables I created appear in ArcCatalog, they do not appear in Windows Explorer, there is only a LOCK file while ArcMap is open.

What should be done?

Comment: Your insert should include extra parentheses  - `cursor.insertRow((str(1)))`

Comment: Thanks for the response! I had not noticed I had done that wrong. However I changed that and it did not affect the errors I was getting.

Comment: you might need a comma after str(1) because its a tuple

Comment: the problem still persists after changing it to a tuple

Comment: SOLVED: The problem seems to have been with not having the .dbf extension at the end of the filename, ArcPy was assuming I was using a Info table instead of a dBASE table. Works fine now. Thank you everyone for the help!

Comment: David, you should re-post your previous comment as an answer and mark it as correct.  Also, I just want to add that I had the same System Error, and it was coming about because the values I was writing did not satisfy the field's domain (ie, I was writing "Road" when the field wanted "RD").

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments, you need to create a tuple for your `insertRow`. Currently your input is a string.

```
>>> ((str(1)))
'1'
>>> ((str(1),))
('1',)
>>>
```

New code:

```
for q in range (0,10):
    cursor.insertRow((str(1),))
```

Comment: I changed it to a tuple and I still get "SystemError: error return without exception set"